# MySQL encoding problem when inserting with Go driver

Tags: mysql, go, encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to store utf-8 text into a table which encoding is latin1_swedish_ci. I can't change the encoding since I do not have direct access to the the db. So what I'm trying is encode the text into latin-1 with this Go library that provides the [encoder](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap) and [this one](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/encoding) that has a function that wraps the encoder so it replaces the invalid characters instead of returning an error.

But when I try to insert the row mysql complains `Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\\xE7\\xE3o pa...' for column 'description' at row 1`.

I tried writing the same text to a file and `file -I` reports this `file.txt: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`.

Example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

func main() {
    s := "foo – bar"

    encoder := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewEncoder()
    encoder = encoding.ReplaceUnsupported(encoder)

    encoded, err := encoder.String(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(encoded)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", encoded)

    /* file test */
    f, err := os.Create("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    w := encoder.Writer(f)
    w.Write([]byte(s))
}
```

I'm probably missing something very obvious but my knowledge about encodings is very poor.

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you expecting `çã` ?

The problem is easily solved.  MySQL will gladly translate from latin1 to utf8 while `INSERTing` text.  But you must tell it that your client is using latin1.  That is probably done during the connection to MySQL, and is probably defaulted to utf8 or UTF-8 or utf8mb4 currently.  It is something like

```
charset=latin1
```